# Как в фрагмент добавить ScrollView?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-scrollview

В MainActivity есть 2 кнопки которые вызывает фрагмент 1 и фрагмент 2. Во фрагменте #1 имеется ScrollView

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(container.getContext());
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(container.getContext());
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    //LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(-2,-2);

    for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(container.getContext());
        textView.setTextSize(30);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(-2,-2));
        textView.setText("Items:" + String.valueOf(i+1));
        linearLayout.addView(textView);

    }
    scrollView.addView(linearLayout);
    container.addView(scrollView);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Так вы его и добавляете, только зачем-то в контейнер, в который потом будет добавлена и вью что вернет метод onCreateView(). Создайте все как надо в XML разметке, к чему этот весь код?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false); ScrollView scrollView = view.findViewById(R.id.frScrollView); LinearLayout linearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout); TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.txtView); for(int i=0; i<5; i++){ textView.setText("Items: " + String.valueOf(i)); linearLayout.addView(textView); } scrollView.addView(linearLayout); return view;` не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если уж вы решили создавать представление программно, то его вы и должны вернуть в своей реализации метода `onCreateView()`:

```java
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // эта строка не используется
    // View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);

    ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(container.getContext());
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(container.getContext());
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    //LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(-2,-2);

    for (int i=0; i<50; i++) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(container.getContext());
        textView.setTextSize(30);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(-2,-2));
        textView.setText("Items:" + String.valueOf(i+1));
        linearLayout.addView(textView);

    }
    scrollView.addView(linearLayout);
    return scrollView; // здесь возвращаем то, что создали
}
```

Правильность параметров вью я не проверял, если что.
Всё то же самое можно было описать в макете `fragment_first.xml` и создать одной строкой

```java
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
```

Но по количеству строк текста похоже что вы пытаетесь сотворить список - а для этого лучше использовать специальные списочные контейнеры. Рекомендуется `RecyclerView`, для примитивных небольших списков-менюшек можно старый `ListView`.

Comment: Спасибо. Разобрался как правильно добавлять элементы. Но элемент добавляется с отступом, и список полностью не виден из-за отступа. Попробовал match_parent и padding не помогает [![введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QibY2.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QibY2.png)